# Unable to ping router?

Tags: windows, router, virtual-machine, connection, ping

I'm running two machines. One of them is a physical machine, the other a virtual machine. Both are meant to connect to the same router.

The physical machine works fine.
Here's ipconfig

[image: ipconfig]

and here it is pinging the router successfully

[image: ping]

yet here, on the other hand, is the ipconfig and failed ping of the virtual machine

[image: ipconfig and ping failure]

What on earth is going wrong? The virtual machine is on a bridged network (so being treated as an independent machine).

Comment: Maybe the default gateway must be configured for the Virt.Box IP cfg?!

Comment: Please consider replacing one of your tags with a `windows` or Windows-related tag instead of redundant networking tags.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you are using both Virtual BOX and VMWare, I have personally seen some incompatibilities in the past - but that was a long time ago.

For now, it is hard to say for certain, but, it looks like your physical machine is connected to the router via wireless and not wired.

If this is static IPs I think I know the problem... I believe that the VM network configuration is only bound to the wired controller in your host, not the wireless one.

If this is via DHCP, I am guessing the VM client you are using has a relay agent or similar - and if it doesn't, I am a little confused on how it was able to get an address.

In either cases, if this doesn't help, please can you try to ping .13 from .14 and the other way round so I can see if there is connectivity at all?

Comment: Thanks for the reply

I'm just using VMWare - and I'm trying to connect to the router wirelessly from both the virtual machine and physical machine.

I am trying to use a static IP with the VM - so this will not work if I try to do this wirelessly? 

Much to my surprise I can't actually ping the physical machine with the virtual machine!

Comment: Ok - As I thought, it looks to me to be quite simple - The VMWare Networking driver hasn't bound itself to the Wireless card - only your wired card... Goto Network Connections and properties of your wireless card and make sure "VMWare Bridge Protocol" is set up there. If it isn't, try to manually install it or do a repair install of Workstation/player.